# Data at the root level is invalid on $.ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I have a simple web service that I am trying to utilize. Obviously, this will be more enahnced down the road but am trying to grasp the basic concept of the ajax call.

**Web Service**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Tools
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for CFServices1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost:51342/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class CFServices1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hellow World";
        }
    }
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CFServices.asmx?/HelloWorld",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

The ajax call appears to work fine as it returns an error:

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.SoapEnvelopeReader.MoveToContent()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocolHelper.GetRequestElement()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.Soap12ServerProtocolHelper.RouteRequest()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.RouteRequest(SoapServerMessage message)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean&amp; abortProcessing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
```

I have tried a couple different things that lead me down the path of the URL property being invalid but since I'm getting an actual response, I'm assuming it's correct. It definitely renders if I navigate to it through a browser. Even if I try and invoke the web service through the asmx page, it all works.

I have tried changing the data type to be plain text but that doesn't work either. Since all the web method does is reutnr the string 'Hellow World', I shouldn't need to pass any arguments but tried passing blank values just in case. Everything either brings me back to the response returning 'undefined', the html markup for the asmx page or this. The 'data at the root element is invalid.' This tells me that either the data being sent to, or recieved from the web service is incorrect or doesn't have the right formatting. This is where I'm getting hung up at because I can't figure out what could possibly be wrong here.

Although this is something probably simple, I'm not finding any luck whatsoever on SOF or other threads. Any helpful insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the webmethod has to be static , and I think that in javascript the response is data.d - webforms ads an annoying "d" - but most importantly why are you using this outdated framework , use MVC

Answer (score 1):

As we are calling it from jquery ie., from script part you need to make the below changes to Webservice part,

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] // Mark it for accessing from script
public class CFServices1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

We need to set script method attribute for the web method as below

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public string HelloWorld()
```

Then while calling it from ajax call just remove ? in url part as below,

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "CFServices.asmx/HelloWorld",
data: "{}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
},
error: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had everything thilsiva suggested but was still receiving this error. It worked on my local development machine but not when deployed. The problem was I was getting my URL from the config file and I was accidentally missing the method name in my deployed version. So make sure you have the method name included if you're in the same situation.

```
url: "CFServices.asmx/HelloWorld",
```

not

```
url: "CFServices.asmx",
```